# In PGSQL JDBC SetClientInfo -- where is this information set stored on the database?

Tags: java, postgresql

The documentation for the JDBC PGSQL driver explains that it stores information set in setClientInfo in a suitable location. Is there a way to access this location from within Queries that are running on the DB. For example, if a trigger gets run, is there a way to grab a property that we set on the connection into the query without the use of the application layer?

> The driver stores the value specified in a suitable location in the database. For example in a special register, session parameter, or system table column. For efficiency the driver may defer setting the value in the database until the next time a statement is executed or prepared. Other than storing the client information in the appropriate place in the database, these methods shall not alter the behavior of the connection in anyway. The values supplied to these methods are used for accounting, diagnostics and debugging purposes only.

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/index.html?org/postgresql/jdbc/PgConnection.html

We have tried looking through any documentation around the JDBC driver and cannot find a location where this is documented, or how to control if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "stored" in the session as a configuration setting with the name `application_name`

You can retrieve it using:

```
current_setting('application_name')
```

The JDBC driver doesn't do anything special. If just runs `set application_name = '...';` after the connection has been established.